# "asn1: structure error: integer not minimally-encoded" when reading an X.509 certificate

Tags: mongodb, go, ssl, certificate, pem

I have an issue with certificates using Go.

I use product written in Go (Mongodb Ops Manager agents) and I have conifgured it to work with my custom CA bundle. After adding new CAs to the bundle I have got the following error:

> asn1: structure error: integer not minimally-encoded

I have written script in go to identify the bad certificate.
After finding this certificate I have tried to parse it using openssl using:

openssl x509 -inform pem -in mycert.pem -text -noout

And it parsed correctly.

I couldn't find anything wrong with this certificate (comparing it to other certificates).

Do you have any idea what can cause this problem?

Unfortunately I can't provide the ceritificate.

Go version: 1.9.4

Comment: `openssl x509` can be more lax about the ASN.1 strictness compared to the Go's implementation. Can you run that command with `-out whatever -outform pem` and without `-text` — to obtain the actual cert and re-add it to the bundle? It also might be of interest to compare the PEM's—just keep in mind that they usually contain some comment cruft at the top, and only the actual base64-encoded block is of interest.

Comment: One more question: how exactly is your question related to Go and MongoDB? I fail to gather that from the question itself.

Comment: (On a side note I'd also add that 1.9.x is is _dirt-old_ and long unsupported. The up-to-date version is 1.15.5.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I have got this problem using mongodb ops manager agents, I have edited my original question. I have tried your suggestion, to reencode the certificate using openssl, and I get the same certificate (checked with diff command), and still same problem with Go error.

Comment: OK, I've delved in the issue tracker and found [#12622](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12622) which looks like your case, and [#13563](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13563) which refers to a CL from the former. You might [look for more issues](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=is%3Aissue+in%3Atitle+encoding%2Fasn1) or open an issue in the tracker. But honestly it looks like you might first need to conduct more testing such as finding a visual ASN.1 parser (actually, the cert is encoded using DER which is one of the three possible binary encoding for the ASN.1 which is syntax)…

Comment: …and try to see whether some bit of the cert is indeed breaks the DER rules or not. Anyway the issue looks like not suitable for SO format; I urge you to ask on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) instead—just be sure to post the question, not just a link to this question (though including one would be fine).